# Using the same EntityManager across multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, entitymanager

I have a JPA environment which has a Application-managed EntityManager. I manually create the entityManagerFactory and create the EntityManager from that. I would like to use the same EntityManager across multiple threads. The documentation says that EntityManager is not thread-safe, but all of my operations will only be reads and no writes will occur through the EntityManager. I also have a timeout on the data in the cache to ensure consistency. In such a scenario, is it ok to use the same instance of the EntityManager across threads? Or can there be any side effects / wrong data on using the same EntityManager across threads.

Thanks

Comment: Even if your EntityManager is for read-only purposes, it still has an internal state. Use an EntityManagerFactory to share among the threads and use a different EntityManager per thread

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, just lock the `EntityManager` instance where ever you use it by using `synchronized`.

So instead of writing

```
em.persist(...);
```

write

```
synchronized (em) {
    em.persist(...);
}
```

You can [read up about the locking mechanism here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)